# initWithContentsOfURL failing to return data

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Below is my code, this code works fine on iphone but same code when i debug using ipad as target it does not work. Please advice me the proper way to call. I cant do Async call as my already other threads are going in background.

```
NSData *ImageData=[[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", SharedGlobals.ReuestURL, temptest]]] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous reasons this may not work. The most likely is that `SharedGlobals.ReuestURL` is `nil`, or `temptest` is nil, or the combination of the two does not create the correct URL (perhaps missing a `/`). Check each piece, and check your logs for errors.

However, this statement makes no sense:

> I cant do Async call as my already other threads are going in background.

Do you mean that this call `initWithContentsOfURL:` is already on a background thread?

Objective-C local variables (`ImageData`) should always start with a lowercase letter (`imageData`).

Comment: But it works on iphone my question is that why its not working on ipad

Comment: This doesn't change anything about how you should debug it. Start by making sure nothing here is nil, and that each part of the expression evaluates to what you think it should.